# My code does't pass the first argument, but no error if(args[1] === 'utility') does't show Discord.js

Tags: arguments, command, discord, discord.js

Hello guys I have a problem with my help command! My arguments don't want to work since i update my command handeler! My command works but my arguments don't. I hope you can help me!

**I want:**

When i type the command: **!help** the bot gives me the first embed `const help = new Discord...`

And when i type the command: **help utility** the bot gives me the second embed `const utility = new Discord...`

**My code:**

```
//from my index
client.on('message', message => {

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

         if (cmd === 'help') {
            client.commands.get('i.help').execute(message, args, Discord);

        } else if {//...

})


//from help file
module.exports = {
    name: 'i.help',
    description: 'help',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {

        if (!args[1]){
        const help = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Commands List')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Fun Commands', value: '`!m help fun`' },
            { name: 'Moderation Commands', value: '`!m help moderation`' },
            { name: 'Utility Commands', value: '`!m help utility`' },
            { name: 'Welcome Messages', value: '`!m help welcome`' },
        )
        .setFooter('For More Information, Check Out Our Discord Server: https://discord.gg/RFEaM7T')
        .setColor(0xf7d078)
    message.channel.send(help);

        }

    //utility help//
    if (args[1] === 'utility'){

        const utility = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Utility Commands')
        .addFields(
            { name: '`!m embed (message)`', value: 'type something in an embed' },
            { name: '`!m ping`', value: 'show\'s your ping' },
            { name: '`!m suggest`', value: 'create a suggestion' },
        )
        .setFooter('For More Information, Check Out Our Discord Server: https://discord.gg/RFEaM7T')
        .setColor(0xf7d078)
    message.channel.send(utility);

    }

//...
```

I've also tried to switch **if (!args[1]){**  in  **if (args[0] === 'help'){**

I am waiting for answers! Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** I finally found an answer... I replaced :

```
client.on('message', message => {

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

         if (cmd === 'help') {
            client.commands.get('i.help').execute(message, args, Discord);

        } else if {//...
```

With:

```
client.on('message', message => {

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    switch(args[0]) {

    case 'help':
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args, version);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer... I replaced :

```
client.on('message', message => {

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

         if (cmd === 'help') {
            client.commands.get('i.help').execute(message, args, Discord);

        } else if {//...
```

With:

```
client.on('message', message => {

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    switch(args[0]) {

    case 'help':
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args, version);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.protorype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) returns the first element in an array, but it also removes that element from the array for further use. That means that wherever you said `args[1]` before should now be `args[0]`

Code snippet example:

```js
// array of arguments
const args = ['hello', 'world'];

// this function does multiple things.
// it returns the first element in the array so we can assign it to a variable,
// but it also removes the element from the original array
const greeting = args.shift();

console.log(greeting);
console.log(args);
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what i want to do... I want to action the commands 1 by 1. Here i understand that i type a command and the bot gives me 2 embeds. I want if i say: **!m help** the bot to send me the help embed and if i say: **!m help moderation** the bot to send me the moderation embed

Comment: What does "I want if I say" mean? I still don't quite understand your question.

Comment: If i type the command: **!help** to give me the first embed. If i type: **!help utility** to give me the second embed (sorry if my exprimation was wrong)

Comment: Have you tried switching the `args[1]` to `args[0]`?

Comment: i can't switch args because if statement doesn't let me `if (cmd === 'help')` **Unexpected token 'if'**